# How to check the VPS server's RAM speed?

Tags: linux, vps

How to check the Linux VPS's RAM speed? Actually as per my VPS plan, I am supposed to get 2GB RAM, but I doubt that I am getting only 128MB. Please help me in finding the server's RAM speed.

Comment: check [this](http://www.phpdeveloping.co.za/memory/how-much-memory-your-script-is-using.html)

Comment: It sounds like you're confusing capacity with speed ... do you actually want the speed, and are you talking about a MHz rating, throughput, response time ... all of the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know the amount of memory (wich seems more probable) you have available, not the speed of RAM, then consider using command free.

```
free -m
```

This will give you the ammount of memory you have available and memory in use, in MB.

See also: [man free](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/free.1.php)

Or if you really want to see your RAM **speed** then this might help

```
sudo lshw -short -C memory
H/W path           Device           Class          Description
==============================================================
/0/0                                memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/3a                               memory         16GiB System Memory
/0/3a/0                             memory         [empty]
/0/3a/1                             memory         8GiB DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2666 MHz (0,4 ns)
/0/3a/2                             memory         [empty]
/0/3a/3                             memory         8GiB DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2666 MHz (0,4 ns)
/0/44                               memory         384KiB L1 cache
/0/45                               memory         1536KiB L2 cache
/0/46                               memory         9MiB L3 cache
/0/100/14.2                         memory         RAM memory
```

[man lshw](https://linux.die.net/man/1/lshw)

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways on how to check the memory usage on linux virtual Private Server (VPS). Refer to this [howto](http://www.ehowstuff.com/how-to-check-memory-usage-on-linux-vps-server/) for more details :

1. Check memory usage using “/proc/meminfo” command:

   ## cat /proc/meminfo
2. Check memory usage using “free -m” command :

   ## free -m
3. Check memory usage using “top” command :

   ## top
4. Check memory usage using “vmstat” command :

   ## vmstat

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find out the memory capacity, you can use "top" on the command-line/terminal.  The total memory is expressed in the top left as ...

```
Mem:    1234567k total,
```

If you want to obtain memory speed information, you'll probably encounter problems under a VPS ... you can always get arbitrary performance figures using something like [RAMspeed](http://alasir.com/software/ramspeed/), but I'm not aware of a way to get accurate frequency/latency/etc. information on a VPS.